# invoking form submit using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

The form submit is not getting invoked with below code, can someone please help on identifying the problem in the code.
Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<body>
  <form id="form" name="form">
    <select name='lstToggleDetails' id='lstToggleDetails' onchange="changeDetailMode1()">
                              <option value="default">Default</option>
                              <option value="details">Details</option>
                            </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" style="display: none;" >
  </form>

  <!--Javascript-->
  <script>
    function changeDetailMode1()
    {
    var form = document.getElementById('form')

    form.addEventListener('submit',function(event){
      event.preventDefault()

      console.log("in submit");
  
    })

    if (document.getElementById("lstToggleDetails").value == "details")
    {
        console.log("submitting form");
        const form1 = document.getElementById("form");
        form1.submit();
    }
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[When you call `.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit):

> This method is similar, but not identical to, activating a form's submit . When invoking this method directly, however:
>
> No submit event is raised. **In particular, the form's onsubmit event handler is not run.**
> Constraint validation is not triggered.

Without a `submit` event, anything attached via `form.addEventListener('submit'` won't run.

Use `.requestSubmit` instead, which *can* be canceled.

You should also probably add the submit handler unconditionally, rather than every time the `<select>` changes.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form')
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log("in submit");
})
function changeDetailMode1() {
  if (document.getElementById("lstToggleDetails").value === "details") {
    console.log("submitting form");
    form.requestSubmit();
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" name="form">
  <select name='lstToggleDetails' id='lstToggleDetails' onchange="changeDetailMode1()">
    <option value="default">Default</option>
    <option value="details">Details</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Register" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working.. As per your answer, i used form.requestSubmit();